# Is it possible to send from a server (not via mobile) a message to a Google Home device?

Tags: grpc, actions-on-google, broadcast, google-assistant-sdk, google-home

I want to write a web app where if a user presses a certain button, it would cause the google nest in my room to say something.

Essentially I want to use an API to send this command to my google nest: "broadcast to bedroom speaker 'button has been pressed' ".

Is this possible with the Assistant / Home API / Actions? I'm reading the documentations, but it's hard to understand what they're capable of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use Google Assistant Relay to relay broadcast messages the same as you would a broadcast message with your voice.

https://github.com/greghesp/assistant-relay

Comment: this is actually what i ended up doing! although it was limited, it got the job done.

Answer (score 1):

While a Google Home device is a [Google Cast surface](https://developers.google.com/cast) the platform does not support programmatic broadcasts. At the same time, casting audio that is the text-to-speech output to a device should be functionally the same.